# XSL to add attribute value based on element value

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the below XML data

```
<RESULT>
  <ROW>
    <TAGA>1</TAGA>
    <TAGB>01-01-2001</TAGB>
  </ROW>
  <ROW>
    <TAGA>2</TAGA>
    <TAGB></TAGB>
  </ROW>
</RESULT>
```

*Output Needed*

```
<RESULT>
  <ROW>
    <TAGA TAGB_DATE="TRUE">1</TAGA>
    <TAGB>01-01-2001</TAGB>
  </ROW>
  <ROW>
    <TAGA TAGB_DATE="FALSE">2</TAGA>
    <TAGB></TAGB>
  </ROW>
</RESULT>
```

I have simplified and obfuscated the actual problem and data, so as to make it simple.

How can I write the XSLT? I have managed to get the TAGB_DATE attribute in the TAGA date with a value. But that value does not change for the 2 different records. I have tried to use choose ... which works. But the for-each part is the one I'm struggling with.

I am new to the world of XSLT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with the [identity transform](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#copying), add a template to match `TAGA`, output `TAGA` with the new attribute and then test `TAGB` to see if it has any text other that whitespace.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="TAGA">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:attribute name="TAGB_DATE">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="normalize-space(../TAGB)">TRUE</xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>FALSE</xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi Daniel. Thanks for the answer. It works. And I didn't even need a for-each. I think the basics need revisiting.

Comment: I think, I realise what sent me down this rabbit hole of "for-each". I was accessing the same value for TAGB as I was using /RESULT/ROW/TAGB. Using ../TAGB (which I guess points to the TAGB element in the current record, resolved it for me. Hopefully this helps another noob who comes looking.